# How to forward Remote-Desktop Port across interfaces using ufw?

Tags: debian, networking, port-forwarding, remote-desktop, ufw

Machine A has two network interfaces:

- Network eth0: `10.10.20.0/24`
- Network wlan0: `192.168.1.145/24`

Machine A has `192.168.1.145` as Default Gateway, and also a route to pass `172.16.0.0/16` to `10.10.20.1`.

I want allow access from wlan0 `192.168.1.145:3389` to `172.16.1.14:3389` using UFW, so I did:

1. `/etc/default/ufw`:

   `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"`
2. `/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf`:

   `net/ipv4/ip_forward=1`
3. `/etc/ufw/before.rules`:

   `*nat
   :PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
   -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 192.168.1.145 --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.1.14
   -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p udp -m udp -d 192.168.1.145 --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.1.14
   COMMIT`
4. Add port `3389` to allow in UFW:
   `ufw allow from any to any port 3389`

But it's not working!

Comment: I came across [PortFusion](http://fusion.corsis.eu/) which makes super easy to do that like this: `PortFusion 3389 ] - 172.16.1.14 3389`, but still no luck with ufw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the command `sudo ufw allow 3389/tcp` and then restarted using `sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart` to solve this same issue on a pi. However my `/etc/ufw/before.rules` file looked like this:

```
# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to eth0
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES
```